Are questions about empirical relations of economical parameters on-topic?
Are questions about empirical relations of economical parameters on-topic on this site? I asked this question on the personal finance site and it (rightfully) has been closed as off-topic since it did not directly relate to personal finance. To be precise, the question was about the empirical relation between the interest rate and the stock market performance. Are such questions on-topic on this site? If yes, could I repost it here or should it be somehow migrated?

IMVHO, it's off-topic in https://quant.stackexchange.com/ but may be of interest in https://economics.stackexchange.com/

Thanks for the advice regarding the economics site, I posted the question there: https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/55531/44271

agreed. It belongs in economics.
